# Finding the $n^{th}$ derivative using Taylor Series

Tags: calculus

I currently have the problem to find the $25^{th}$ derivative of $f(x)=(1+x^2)^{13}$ at $x=0$. I'm not sure if my reasoning is correct here but I use the definition of binomial expansion which is,

\begin{equation}
(1+x^2)^{13}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{13\choose n}x^{2n}
\end{equation}

Then I equate it to the definition of Taylor Series. Which I get the equation,

\begin{equation}
\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^{2n}=\frac{13!}{n!(n-13)!}x^{2n}
\end{equation}

Cancelling out terms I end up with the answer,

\begin{equation}
f^{(15)}(0)=\frac{13!}{2!}
\end{equation}

Is this the correct way to find the $n^{th}$ derivative using the two definitions?

Comment: Hint : There are only even powers of $x$ in expansion. Upto which power?

Comment: Since we're finding the 25th derivative would it be upto the power of 26?

Comment: Yes. You're correct.

Comment: So instead of using n=15, I should use n=13? So my answer would just be 13! ?

Comment: there is no point to compute the $25^{th}$ derivative. Since the function is even, all its odd-order derivatives vanish at $x = 0$.